# Extract value from array when condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple array:

```
var c = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
```

I am iterating through the array to try and return the value which meets the condition:

```
$.each(c, function() {
    // I need to pass each value from the array as the
    // last argument in the function below
    var p = get_shutter_price( width, height, c );
    if ( p > 0 ) {
        // Return the value from the array which allowed the condition to be met
        console.log( c );
    }
});
```

This does not work as expected because the entire array is being passed into the function.

**How do I return the value form the array which allowed the condition to be met?**

For example, if the number **8** from the array is the one that returns a price greater than **0**, then return **8**.

Comment: All values, or only the first to meet the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you want all values from `c` that meet the conditions, simply [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var c = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

var conditionsMet = c.filter(function (value) {
  return 0 < get_shutter_price(width, height, value);
});
```

with `conditionsMet[0]` then being the first to meet the conditions.

Comment: Great approach! I think you meant `conditionsMet[0]`, but I would think that if none of the elements get returned you end up with `[]` and so you would have to run a test before trying to retrieve `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and clean, and exactly what I needed

Comment: @PeterKA You're right of course in both cases. Though regarding the latter, I tend to not include such test here on SO as they are more or less required every time. And as such would just clutter the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand correctly you need `array.prototype.filter` method to filter your array depend on condition.

```
var b = c.filter(function(val) {
  return val > 0;
});
```

in your case just put your condition like this:

```
var b = c.filter(function(val) {
  return get_shutter_price( width, height, val ) > 0;
});
```

It will return you a new array with this condition.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) there are two parameters you can use in the callback function, the first is the index of the item you are iterating over, the second is the value of the item.

```
$.each(c, function(index, val) {
    // I need to pass each value from the array as the
    // last argument in the function below
    var p = get_shutter_price( width, height, val );
    if ( p > 0 ) {
        // Return the value from the array which allowed the condition to be met
        console.log( c=val );
    }
});
```

Comment: Would be a better answer if you explain what was wrong and how you fixed it rather than just planking some code down.

Comment: Thanks, I was working on it, just took me a minute to look up the docs.

Answer (score 0):

use `this` instead of `c`, to pass the current iterating value, and you are 100% right that the whole array is passed when you use `c`, so use `this` to pass the current item which is being iterated -

```
$.each(c, function() {
    // I need to pass each value from the array as the
    // last argument in the function below
    var p = get_shutter_price( width, height, this );
    if ( p > 0 ) {
        // Return the value from the array which allowed the condition to be met
        console.log( this );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each(c, function(index, item) {
// do something with `item` 
});
```

In your code you missed to pass index and item as arguments to function   (here index is optional)